# Android intents repository

Tags: android, repository, android-intent

There are many intents an Android developer can use - [the ones that arrive with the OS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), [OpenIntents](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/), and several others.

Is there a site that lists all possible intents and their parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Registry of intents protocols](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable)

=)

UPDATE::

[Intents List: Invoking Google Applications on Android Devices](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Comment: OpenIntents is definitely not a comprehensive list, but it is the best we have for now.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no site that lists *all* possible `Intents` and their parameters. As Jorgesys points out, OpenIntents started this, but crowdsourcing an `Intent` catalog never really took off.